# What's a good way to implement menus/scenes with SDL2 in C?

Tags: c, sdl

I'm making a game using SDL2. I was testing menus but a bug had me think I had to change my approach. I used to have a separate while loop for every menu, but now I'm trying to have a single loop for the whole game which handles different menus depending on the value of a variable (nested loops became a mess to handle). I thought about it for a while, but the variety of the needs of the menus gave me a lot of trouble. If anyone can suggest me some good approach, here is what it requires:

- Differentiated event handling (a menu should handle player movement keys, another some handle other things...);
- A way to free every variable declared with malloc() once a menu stops running;
- An initialization that runs only once before each menu loop starts.

I hope someone can give me a good approach with pseudocode or just normal explaination, thanks in advance to those who'll help!

Comment: Do you plan to have situations in which you will have more than one menu open at the same time?

Comment: No, i need only 1 menu to be open at the same time, so i'm guessing the idea you commented might do fine. Thanks!

Comment: So, to check if i got this well: i create a scruct called menu which will have a function pointer for initializing it, one for closing it and one for handling input. Do i update the scene in the event handling function too, or do i need a separate function for that? And what about the rendering?

Comment: I have now created an answer from two of my comments. I have therefore deleted these comments, because they are no longer necessary. I suggest that you repost the question in your previous comment as a comment to my answer, because it is related to my answer.

Comment: Since you have not yet reposted your question as a comment to my answer, I will answer here, for now: If the menu does not have to be updated in every frame, but only when there is user input, then it would probably be appropriate to add a pointer to an `SDL_Texture` or `SDL_Surface` to `struct menu`. This data member should always contain the current graphical representation of the menu. That way, the menu's input function could update this data member whenever it is necessary, and your game's main loop would only have to read this data member whenever it wants to render a frame.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. My game needs to be updated every frame, and not only when the user provides input. Do i need to make a separate function then?

Comment: Do the graphics of the menu also have to be updated in every frame? Or would it be sufficient if the graphics of the menu is only updated on input?

Comment: If the entire game, including the graphics of the menu, must be updated every frame and not only when there is input, then you may want to consider adding another function pointer to `struct menu`, which is called once per frame. When your game's main loop calls this function, it instructs the menu to update its `SDL_Texture` in the `struct menu`. After the function returns, the game's main loop can use the updated `SDL_Texture` of the menu to render the game's current frame.

Comment: Got it, I'm sure function pointers should do it. Thanks for all the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider doing the following:

Every menu defines its own object of `struct menu`, which contains at least the following three function pointers:

1. A pointer to a function which is called whenever the menu opens, so memory for the menu's data can be allocated, and the data can be initialized.
2. A pointer to a function which is called whenever the menu closes, so that all memory allocated by the menu can be freed.
3. A pointer to the menu's input function which is called whenever the program receives input. This function will return `true` if the menu handles the input, or `false` if it does not handle the input, because it is unrelated to the menu (for example if the input is a key for player movement).

Your program should have a pointer to a `struct menu` which always specifies the currently active menu, or `NULL` if no menu is active. Whenever your program's main loop receives input, it calls the function pointer for the input function of the currently active menu. If the menu's input function returns `true`, then the game's main loop will ignore the input, but if the menu's input function returns `false` (for example if the input is a key for player movement), then the game's main loop will handle the input itself.